# Conditional props typing based on the content of these props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a `Selector` component that takes a classic pair of `value` and `onChange` props. However, I would like the types of these props to be defined by the content of the rest of the props.

When there is only just `value` and `onChange` being used, I would like `value` to be of type `never` and `onChange` of type `(value: never) => void`.

If I add the prop `user`, I would like to type `value` as `User` (a predefined type defined elsewhere).

If I use two additional props `user` and `team`, I would like to type `value` to be `User | Team`.

Etc., based on a predefined list of possible additional props (`user`, `team`, etc. Each one adding a type possibility to `value`).

Here is what I tried :

```js
type User = {
    __typename: 'User';
    id: string
}

type Team = {
    __typename: 'Team';
    id: string
}

type Organization = {
    __typename: 'Organization';
    id: string
}

type Mapper = {
    user: User
    team: Team
    organization: Organization
}

type InferValue<H extends PropsHandlers> = Mapper[keyof H]; // Doesn't work (Type 'keyof H' cannot be used to index type 'Mapper')

type PropsHandlers = Partial<{
    user: {
        variables: object
        onSelect(user: User): void
    }
    team: {
        variables: object
        onSelect(team: Team): void
    }
    organization: {
        variables: object
        onSelect(organization: Organization): void
    }
}>

type Props<H extends PropsHandlers> = {
    value: InferValue<H>;
    onChange(value: InferValue<H>): void
} & H

function Component<H extends PropsHandlers>(props: Props<H>) {
    return null;
}

Component({
    value: { __typename: 'User', id: 'test' },
    onChange: value => undefined,
    user: {
        variables: {},
        onSelect: user => undefined
    }
})
```

But this doesn't work. Any help please ? Thank you !

**EDIT :**

I found the following to be working, but I have to explicitly list the generic parameter. Is there a way to infer it ?

```js
type User = {
    __typename: 'User';
    id: string
}

type Team = {
    __typename: 'Team';
    id: string
}

type Organization = {
    __typename: 'Organization';
    id: string
}

type Mapper = {
    user: User
    team: Team
    organization: Organization
}

type Handler<K extends keyof Mapper> = {
    variables: object
    onSelect(item: Mapper[K]): void
}

type Handlers<K extends keyof Mapper> = {
    [k in K]: Handler<k>
}

type Props<K extends keyof Mapper> = {
    value: Mapper[K];
    onChange(value: Mapper[K]): void
} & Handlers<K>

function Component<K extends keyof Mapper>(props: Props<K>) {
    return null;
}

Component<'user' | 'team'>({
    value: { __typename: 'User', id: 'test' },
    onChange: value => undefined,
    user: {
        variables: {},
        onSelect: user => undefined
    },
    team: {
        variables: {},
        onSelect: team => undefined
    }
})
```

**[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgMUQQwOYFsIDthQC8UA3gFBSVQD61okuaOAXFAOTxJsDcFVAlgBNWcYIn64MZAL5ky9aABUITVJhz4ipPpVoLGLdsqY8dUISLESps%20eGgB5RBjS5%20ALzTB%20Ae1xrsPAJicioaOnsDCFY2Jxc3T28-UzCLKFFxSRk5BSgAWTQwSEQtUKoAVwREVk4UdED8M2AVLFZjLACNYDMfZ1cPL19cVjj%20xKHOoOy7SCgACVdBABskAB4AaSgIAA9m3EE4KABrCBAfADN8wuKAPlKzADc0cTQAIxW4Vh9XgCsIAGNumE-ABlCArQEACn4zVaVyKSAA2usALoASlYDx8QmmuQW%20xWiDgGy2uzwB2Opwu8Nu9zCiKO5lwUFRrHxyzWRxuuPsUAACogfGBiZsdnsKSczpcCgjEHcQo80EtytEaUjUbxgbgAMIAC1cGAgkKeytVMuKyPRmOxghkUAAZPNFoSRdyyOdyrhAUMoNqfFgwH4giSxeTDpLqeakDdIWBBcLWAKha60dowogIMByohmbhykslrxbH6A0H8Ks2JUuFAAD7sZomGNlSgmlWsEjhfRMVUcKpsAA05mE9YgojYUGk-Z6Ov1klVreghDunsEEHOEggginYSr1TTYSoTxe71H7cnZi1YIhwFYu6Iy-2a43trC57CDbhzYPR-4bw%20Z%203A9KFBcEARvKAP3vKAVyfXBNzMWRpDRMggA)**

Comment: Blecch, the type inference algorithm in TS is not going to do what you want here, I think.  The closest I can get is [this](https://tsplay.dev/vWkrPm), and it requires that the argument to `Component` have its callback arguments *fully annotated*; you can't really have contextual callback parameter inference and generic type parameter inference for the same function argument.  Or there's [this](https://tsplay.dev/4WyJJw) which is not exactly what you want (it lets you pass some wrong things to `value` and `onChange`) but at least you get some contextual typing.

Comment: Which, if any of those, should I flesh out into an answer?  The fundamental thing blocking you is the same problem as in [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872), which is listed as a design limitation

Comment: @jcalz The first one seems to fit best. However, due to the complexity, I went with explicit generics. It's not a huge price to pay. You can still post your answer, I will accept it.